# Terraform create security group permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am using the following Terraform to create a security group for an EC2 instance:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_http_access" {
  name        = "${var.prefix}-ecs-host-sg"
  description = "HTTP Access"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    description = "HTTP Access"
  }
}
```

This works fine, however I'm trying to fine tune the permissions of the user that runs this. My goal is to ensure the user can only create instance types of `t2.micro` in a specific region.

I can successfully limit the instance type using this policy which is working fine:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": [
                “*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when specifying specific resources (I have confirmed all of them are included), it fails with `Error creating Security Group: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc-peering-connection/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpn-gateway/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:reserved-instances/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpn-connection/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:launch-template/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-acl/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:placement-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:internet-gateway/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:route-table/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:dhcp-options/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::spot-instance-request/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:customer-gateway/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::fpga-image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Why would it work with a wildcard on `Resource` but not when listing all of the resources individually?

Comment: How sure are you that you were using the wildcard policy when creating that security group? Because that shouldn't work at all so I'd be very confused if it does. The solution to this is that you need to split your statements so that the condition only applies to things that make sense (instance managing permissions). Also I'd change your policy to be controlling the actions, not the list of resources like that and I'd be a little bit surprised if that doesn't fail in weird ways.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR, I tested it and I'm sure the wildcard works because the SG is created and it's the only EC2 statement in the policy, not sure why it wouldn't? Security groups are under `ec2` and it permits all actions on all resources. The string condition is only if the `ec2:InstanceType` string exists in the request. I agree that the statements should be split and I plan to do that once I figure out what the issue is here.

Comment: Ah, I misread that. I think this is just that IAM policies fall over if the action type is paired with a resource restriction that it can't use. Security group permissions only allow your `arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/*` or `arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/security-group-id` resource. See more in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#security-group). It might also be unhappy with the condition as it's not an allowed condition for the action but maybe the `ifExists` will let it through.